# Поиск фраз по "ИЛИ"

Tags: mongodb, полнотекстовый-поиск

Требуется организовать поиск по полнотекстовому индексу фразы `Розовый слон` или `Сиреневый трактор`

`$text: { $search: "'Розовый слон' 'Сиреневый трактор'" }`

Выдаёт все строки, которые содержат хоть одно слово, например, `трактор`.

`$text: { $search: "\"Розовый слон\" \"Сиреневый трактор\"" }`

`$text: { $search: "'\"Розовый слон\"' '\"Сиреневый трактор\"'" }`

Выдаёт только строки, содержащие и `Розовый слон`, и `Сиреневый трактор`

Comment: Пробуй сделать запрос именно ИЛИ `{$or: [{первое_условие}, {второе_условие}]}`

Comment: @ksa полнотекстовый поиск не работает через `or` ошибка `"message" : Too many text expressions`

Comment: Тут вообще предлагают отказаться от полнотекстового поиска (для ИЛИ) и использовать регулярку... https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.4ae98f2e-64d1f3c3-880989a6-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/32478824/mongodb-full-text-search-for-multiple-phrases

Comment: @ksa к сожалению регулярка идёт по fullscan

Comment: Как вариант - сделать запрос по каждой фразе и результаты объединить...

Comment: @ksa опять же проблема с пересекающимися ответами, плюс нагрузка на БД, плюс различные вариации or and с другими условиями, плюс группировка и сортировка.

Comment: Зато уже есть из чего выбирать... :)

Comment: Вместо `search` использовать `find` с `or`. Это будет использовать индекс (если он есть). Не полнотекстовый индекс, а обычный.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov какой поиск? по regex? он не использует индекс Mongo.